# GWT/StockWatcher: can't connect the server

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm following the steps of StockWatcher app. After running the app in Eclipse I get an URL (http://127.0.0.1:8888/StockWatcher.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997) that shows this:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/images/CreateStarterApplication.png

I insert my name in the field but I get this error:

> An error occurred while attempting to contact the server. Please check
>   your network connection and try again.

I'm getting this output in Eclipse:

```
Initializing App Engine server
   [WARN] ********************************************************
There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.6.0
Timestamp: Tue Oct 18 01:46:22 CEST 2011
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.5.5
Timestamp: Sat Oct 08 03:15:30 CEST 2011
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Please visit http://code.google.com/appengine for the latest SDK.
********************************************************

Nov 15, 2011 5:24:37 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Nov 15, 2011 5:24:37 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /home/javier/programacion/StockWatcher/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Nov 15, 2011 5:24:37 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /home/javier/programacion/StockWatcher/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
Nov 15, 2011 6:24:45 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Nov 15, 2011 5:24:52 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /favicon.ico
Nov 15, 2011 5:24:52 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /favicon.ico
Nov 15, 2011 5:24:58 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /stockwatcher/greet
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 17 in method com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; at offset 4
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I'm running apache2 in local.

Any idea?

Comment: Well, if you are just running the webapp out of Eclipse, using the GWT plugin - you don't need apache running. I would turn it off. Also, check your gwt-servlet.jar in the war/ dir in the web app. Make sure everything is on the same version.

Comment: @EdH. I stop apache2 but the error is the same. Anyway I would not like to stop apache because I working in another web apps that use apache..I check gwt-servlet.jar but I don't know exactly what to check..If someone wants to have a look at it, here it is: http://www.mediafire.com/?d59qaj5icbdpdom

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem with Eclipse and starting a new WebApplication. I solved it by opening project properties, java compiler, checked enable project specific settings and used compiler compliance level 1.6
Also it gaved me a message that i need to have the 1.6 JRE loaded.
You find that also in project properties, java build path, Libraries tab, edit JRE system library and make sure you have JRE6 in default setting or you can add it and select it for use.

Comment: changing language level from 1.7 to 1.6 did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: ... 4 years later at GWT 2.6: I had the exact same problem, but now with GWT 2.6 the solution was to downgrade to JRE7 from JRE8 (where GWT 2.6 indeed supports up to JRE7).  This is true in GWT2.7 too.

Answer (score 0):

You SDK is not updated one. please change your sdk and try it.