# Starting with GWT and eclipse

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, tomcat, google-chrome

I try to work with GWT so I follow [the google getting started page](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html)

I have the started page, but when I clicked on "send", I have this error on my browser (Chrome):

```
Remote Procedure Call - Failure
Sending name to the server:
GWT User

Server replies:
An error occurred while attempting to contact the server. Please check your network connection and try again.
```

and this error on my console under eclipse:

```
janv. 24, 2012 1:50:27 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
Avertissement: Error for /save/greet
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 17 in method com.epitech.save.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; at offset 4
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Since two hours, I'm searching a solution on the web but without results.

Anyone have an idea to fix my problem?

here is my system specification:
Windows seven x64
Tomcat v7.0
Java jre7
eclipse Indigo Service Release 1

Comment: Could you post the code that is being executed, along with the code that is calling it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GWT/StockWatcher: can't connect the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140770/gwt-stockwatcher-cant-connect-the-server)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switch to the JDK6, because Jetty included in GPE is not working too well with JDK7.

Comment: ... 3 years later at GWT 2.6:  I had the exact same problem, but now with GWT 2.6 the solution was to downgrade to JRE7 from JRE8 (where GWT 2.6 indeed supports up to JRE7).

Comment: That is true in GWT 2.7.0. also